# how to make custom drop down in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

how to make chip in single select dropdown in react ?Actually in `multi-select` there is chip is created as show in below example .can we do the same this in the single selection?
https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-example-1k9ij

```
const DropdownExampleClearableMultiple = () => (
  <Dropdown
    clearable
    fluid

    search
    selection
    options={countryOptions}
    placeholder='Select Country'
  />
)
```

if you remove `multiple` from the `Dropdown` component then it becomes single selected .but it does not create ship how if create chip in single selected dropdown

API
[Dropdown](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-multiple-selection)

[image]

This type of chip in single selected dropdown

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

you may add `clearable' props to dropdown component to let user remove the selection and re-select again

```
const DropdownExampleClearableMultiple = () => (
  <Dropdown
    clearable
    fluid
    search
    selection
    options={countryOptions}
    placeholder='Select Country'
    clearable
  />
)
```

Feel free to check the [API](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-clearable)